# Why errors when filters DataTable with CollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter

As titled.

So I was successfully to put `DataTable` into my `CollectionView` with using:

```
    ICollectionView _collectionView { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView collectionView {......}

            DataTable myDataTable= new DataTable();
            myConnection.Open();
            dbAdpater.Fill(myDataTable);
            myConnection.Close();
            var collectionList= (newLeadTable as IListSource).GetList();
            this.collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collectionList);
```

I know each of the object in the list is `DataRowView` and as I tested with iterating the data and I can see is stored properly.

The `DataGrid` was display properly when I execute the code.

But once I added the Filter:

```
            this.collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(
                (obj) =>
                {
                    return false; //Just for testing propose
                }
            );
```

When I execute the code is giving me error:

> Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in assembly 'TestWPF,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file
>   'TestWPF;component/Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

And output:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

I also tried to stores converts the `DataTable` into a list of `custom object` for filtering, but is working fine.

So I wonder what did I done wrong when filtering with `DataTable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections

> To improve performance, collection views for ADO.NET DataTable or DataView objects delegate sorting and filtering to the DataView.

The `BindingListCollectionView` does not support filtering. Instead, you have to use the [CustomFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.customfilter.aspx) property which takes a filter string and uses it as the value for the underlying `DataView.RowFilter` property. The string value is SQL that you would use to construct the WHERE clause in a SELECT query.

```
this.collectionView.CustomFilter = "Price > 20";
```

If you want to use multiple conditions, then you have to string them together with AND or OR (just like SQL).

Comment: hmm? I am using CollectionView for ADO.NET DataTable and filtering to the DataView....

Comment: Your code suggests you are filtering on the CollectionView. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073.aspx