# How to Filter values of a ComboBox in WPF via Entity Framework with a Filter?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, combobox

My issue is simple, I have to load values from a table to the ComboBox for a particular field via Entity Framework. eg. ConfigID , ConfigGroup , ConfigName

I need to load the values of ConfigName to the ComboBox1.(Which I did successfully)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="configNameComboBox" Grid.Column="2" DisplayMemberPath="ConfigName"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="3,5,0,5" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

The problem is that I need to filter the values which will be displayed in the ComboBox according ConfigGroup. eg. ConfigGroup: Gr1 , Gr2 , Gr3. 
I only need to display values in the comboBox which has Gr1 as the ConfigGroup.

How can I achieve this , is there any place to write any queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper `CollectionViewSource` over your collection where you can provide `Filter`.
Bind with that `CollectionViewSource` instead.

Refer to this [detailed sample at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case CollectionViewSource is something new to you.

---

**XAML**

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="filteredCollection"
                          Source="{Binding SourceCollection}" 
                          Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
</Grid.Resources>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource filteredCollection}}"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Config config = e.Item as Config;
    if (config != null)
    {
        if (config.ConfigGroup == "G1")
            e.Accepted = true;
        else
            e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting InvalidOperationException saying that 

'System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView' view does not support filtering.

Comment: `BindingListCollectionView` doesn't support filtering. You need to wrap your collection inside List so that `ListCollectionView` gets created. You can refer to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15819225/632337).