# How to filter records in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, visual-studio-2017, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to filter my data for the selected column based on a search box. I have this so far, based on this post: [filter wpf datagrid values from a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099042/filter-wpf-datagrid-values-from-a-textbox)

DataGridCollection:

```
public ICollectionView DataGridCollection
{
   get { return _dataGridCollection; }
   set { _dataGridCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DataGridCollection"); }
}
```

Filter collection:

```
private void FilterCollection()
{
    if (_dataGridCollection != null)
    {
        _dataGridCollection.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Data source:

```
DataTable pixsellOrders = SqlConnect(query);    
Grid.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate { DataGridCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(pixsellOrders); });
DataGridCollection.Filter = new Predicate<object>(filter);
```

Filter button (right-click):

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = "";
        FilterBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate { filter = FilterBox.Text; });

        if (filter == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no filter");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filter);
            FilterCollection();
        }
    }
```

Based on example:

```
private bool filter(object item)
    {
        if (item.Subject.Contains(_searchstr) || item.Reference.Contains(searchstr))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ResultsWindow}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="20,45,20,60" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridCollection}"  >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Filter" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                Value="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="BtnBack" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="76" Click="BtnBack_Click"/>
    <TextBox Height="27" Margin="65,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="524" Name="FilterBox"/>
    <Label Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

In the example the columns are being declared explicitly in the filter (private bool filter). I would like to filter only on the column that is selected (right click the column header and choose filter from the context menu). How do I tweak what I have to do this? Unfortunately I don't have much experience with XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to filter a `DataTable` is to set the `RowFilter` property of the `DataView`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx. There are some examples available here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/.

You cannot filter a `DataView` of a `DataTable` using the `Filter` property of the `ICollectionView`. This is not supported:

[Why errors when filters DataTable with CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385489/why-errors-when-filters-datatable-with-collectionview)

Answer (score 0):

In general you would implement a search-by-column feature with some special syntax in the search box, i.e. `column:value`.

```
private static bool TryGetValue(string search, out string column, out string value)
{
    // just an example, should be made more robust

    column = null;

    value = null;

    var match = Regex.Match(search, @"^(\w+):(.*)$");

    if (!match.Success)
        return false;

    column = match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
    value = match.Groups[2].Value.Trim();

    return true;
}
```

Example:

```
var strings = new[]
{
    "column1:abcd",
    "qwerty:asdfg",
    "1234:5678"
};

foreach (var search in strings)
{
    string column;
    string value;

    if (TryGetValue(search, out column, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Column: '{column}'\tValue: '{value}'");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid syntax");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Column: 'column1'       Value: 'abcd'
Column: 'qwerty'        Value: 'asdfg'
Column: '1234'  Value: '5678'
```

By doing so the user is in charge to fill the column and your code will not be hard-coded.

You could enhance that by *if there's no prefix column in the search query, then it means search all columns*.

Also, you could implement auto-suggestion in that search box.

Etc ...

Comment: The user is never touching the column, the columns are populated from an SQL query. I would like the user to enter a string in the search box and then filter a column on that string (search for that string in all rows of the column). It may be I'm misunderstanding your answer

Comment: Basically what i'm suggesting is a search box like the one on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), it's simple and easy to use/implement.